# Split column with data.frames into multiple rows

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a data.frame where one column contains data.frames.

```
data <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2))
data$DF <- list(data.frame(x = c(1,2), y = c(3,5)), data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = c(3,5,7)))
data
ID      DF
1       1, 2, 3, 5
2       1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 7
```

I would like to split this data into a long format.

```
ID      DF.x     DF.y
1       1        3
1       2        5
2       1        3  
2       2        5
2       3        7
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: You can use `unnest` from `tidyr` i.e. `unnest(data)` or with `base R` `cbind(ID = rep(data$ID, sapply(data$DF, nrow)), do.call(rbind, data$DF))`

Comment: Thanks that was easy :D

Comment: You should add it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you, I posted as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `unnest` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
unnest(data)
```

---

Or a `base R` option would be

```
cbind(ID = rep(data$ID, sapply(data$DF, nrow)), do.call(rbind, data$DF))
```